# Handling json Form with jQuery on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, google-app-engine

I am having some problems with making jQuery work on GAE python 2.7 . **The main problem is jQuery cant catch the json data returned by the server.**

A simple comment form with nothing special:

```
<form action="/postcomment/" method="post" id="commentform">
  <input type="text" name="author" id="author"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Name: (required)') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name: (required)';" {% if name %}value="{{ name }}"{% else %}value="Name: (required)"{% endif %} size="22" tabindex="1" aria-required='true' />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  onfocus="if(this.value=='E-Mail: (required)') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-Mail: (required)';" {% if email %}value="{{ email }}"{% else %}value="E-Mail: (required)"{% endif %} size="22" tabindex="2" aria-required='true' />
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="3"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My jQuery code (only structure to make it simpler):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
$.ajax({
 dataType: 'json',
 beforeSubmit: function() {
 },
 timeout: 60000,
 error: function(request,error) {
 },
  success: function(data) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   //blah blah...
   } // End success
}); // End ajax method
});
```

On the server side:

```
class PostComment(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    response = {'errorcode': 0}
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

The result is:
After I click the "submit" button, My Firefox 3.6 browser says: There is "application/json" file, do you want to open it with which tool?

I was expecting jQuery to catch this 'json' data and process it. But it didnt happen.

I believe I am almost there but something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel the default action of the form, which is to submit (which cancels any running JavaScript AJAX query in progress):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSubmit: function() {
     },
     timeout: 60000,
     error: function(request,error) {
     },
      success: function(data) {
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       //blah blah...
       } // End success
    }); // End ajax method
    return false; // Cancel default action.
});
```

By returning `false` from the click handler, the *normal* form action, which is for the browser to submit the data to the URL named in the `action` attribute, is not executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! However, if I add the recaptcha script in the form:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=xxxx" > </script>` The same json file problem appear again. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @GabySolis: Sorry, I don't know why that'd be, I am not familiar with the ReCaptcha JS. Perhaps you can make that a new question so someone that does know can help you?